# Atlassian Stash SSL certificate renewal issue

Tags: git, ssl, certificate

So we have a self-hosted version of Atlassian BitBucket running on Ubuntu server which holds the code repository. We use a SSL certificate from DigiCert . Every year we renew the certificate which has never caused issues.
However this time most of the developers are getting the following error when pushing and pulling code from GIT after the certificate was renewed

fatal: unable to access : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

All searches online point to this error when you 're using a self-signed or internal PKI certificate. We are totally stumped on why a certificate issued by a public authority like DigiCert is getting this error . Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Public certificate authorities don't issue certificates directly from their root, but instead through an intermediate certificate (for security and administrative reasons).

[image]

Without having the intermediates, it's impossible to make the link between your cert and DigiCert This means that in order to verify your server certificate, it's not enough to just trust the DigiCert root – clients must also obtain all intermediate issuers in the chain.

Web browsers can do so in various ways: they can fetch certificates from the AIA URL stored in your server cert, and they can cache intermediate issuers seen previously, so various incomplete configurations *appear* to work "fine" when visited through a browser.

But barebones TLS clients aren't as flexible (I mean, they cannot make any extra HTTP requests, nor expect to have a writable cache) and so the intermediate certificates must be supplied *by the TLS server itself*.

- If the webserver takes a single PEM (.crt) file, then that file needs to have the correct intermediate certificates *appended* to it.

  If DigiCert sent you a .zip with the certificate via email, one of the included files is the intermediate cert, and you can concatenate both files using `cat` or a text editor. (The server cert always goes first, its direct issuer next, and so on. Root would go at the end, but it's redundant here so don't include it.)
- If the webserver wants a PKCS#12 file, and you made that file with `openssl export`, then re-export it and specify the intermediates using OpenSSL's `-CAfile` option. (Alternatively, give it the combined .crt as `-cert` instead.)
- If the webserver uses a Java keystore, `keytool -importcert` might work? (Recent versions of Java support and indeed prefer directly using PKCS#12 files as keystores, so this might be redundant. Honestly I've no clue.)

Verify your configuration using [SSL-Tools](https://ssl-tools.net/webservers) or [Qualys SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/). Just opening the site with a web browser is *not* a good test, due to what I already mentioned.